# asphalt 8 local wifi race

Tags: asphalt-8

In their online support centre [here](http://support.gameloft.com/OnlineAndSocial/showSelection/283/) GameLoft says :

> Some of our players have informed us that they are unable to play a
>   local Wi-Fi race. In order to do this, please make sure you have the
>   same versions of Asphalt 8 on both of your devices, and that the
>   devices run the same operating systems and firmware versions. Please
>   note that the feature is currently unavailable on some devices, such
>   as HTC devices. Please accept our sincere apologies for the temporary
>   inconvenience.

I have tried many times but every time I create a room, Its waiting for god know who to come join my room. And those willing to join my room see empty rooms screens.

No where could I find about how much minimum audience/players are required for Local Wi-Fi race.

EDIT: **Long overdue** response from Gameloft insists on Game version must have been different in my case.

Comment: have reported an bug with GameLoft as well, see what they have to say

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking, do you mind editing your question?